# Task with while(true) consume a lot of CPU

Tags: c#, multithreading

I've got a code which creates a task with infinite loop in it for repeating action, checking ftp or web site for example

```
public static Task Start(Action<WorkContext> action, WorkContext wcntx, int timeout)
{
    AutoResetEvent resetEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    wcntx.ResetEvents.Add(resetEvent);

    Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        wcntx.CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

        while (true)
        {
            action(wcntx);

            //Delay
            resetEvent.WaitOne(timeout,true);

            //Checking CancellationToken
            wcntx.CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        }

    }, wcntx.CancellationToken);  

    return task; 
}
```

It consumes a lot of CPU, according to perfomance profiler the main CPU load is in this part

```
resetEvent.WaitOne(timeout,true);
```

is there any solution to fix this?

Comment: What's the value of your `timeout`?

Comment: Different every time. I've got over 50 such tasks at once, timeouts from 10ms to 30ms

Comment: I'm not so experienced in using the profiler, but I think it shows that this code is run very often, but not by which task. If you have _50_ tasks each running every _10-30ms_, it's no suprise that this eats up your cpu. Plus 50 tasks also need a lot of scheduling.

Comment: btw: if your `resetEvent`s are just used to cancel, you may use the [`CancellationToken.WaitHandle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken.waithandle(v=vs.110).aspx) itself.

Comment: nope its for making delay only

Comment: that's what i meant, you can make that delay by waiting on the `wcntx.CancellationToken.WaitHandle` and don't need an extra `AutoResetEvent`

Comment: are you using the sampling profiler?

Comment: Why are you using an `AutoResetEvent` and not `await Task.Delay`? An `AutoResetEvent` is not task-aware (and fairly inefficient, because it's backed by a kernel object).

Comment: Are you sure it's CPU usage and not time consumed? Of course the profiler will show that a 30ms delay will consume 30ms. Besides that, the scheduling generated from 50 threads waking up 30 times a second is not too bad. This should not cause major issues. 1500 context switches per second is what my machine does when idle.